# Calling function with PySimpleSOAP

Tags: python, pysimplesoap

I'm trying to invoke a function using a web service that seems to work fine using SoapUI, but not with pysimplesoap. The WSDL has this function:

```
Name: getAvailableDates
Input {'getAvailableDates': {u'criteria': {u'id': <type 'str'>, u'appointmentDurationMin': <type 'int'>}, u'numberOfSlots': <type 'int'>}}
```

But when I invoke it like so:

```
client.getAvailableDates(criteria={'id' : '1', 'appointmentDurationMin' : 60}, numberOfSlots=10)
```

But it always returns a cryptic error that I don't understand:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysimplesoap/client.py", line 181, in <lambda>
    return lambda *args, **kwargs: self.wsdl_call(attr, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysimplesoap/client.py", line 346, in wsdl_call
    return self.wsdl_call_with_args(method, args, kwargs)
  File "/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysimplesoap/client.py", line 370, in wsdl_call_with_args
    response = self.call(method, *params)
  File "/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pysimplesoap/client.py", line 269, in call
    fault = operation['faults'][detailXml.children()[0].get_name()]
KeyError: u'ns2:TTServiceException'
```

Thoughts on what I might be doing wrong? Appreciate any help.